# Deleted Core Data records don't disappear in watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, watchos

I got an app in iOS & watchOS in SwiftUI with a Core Data database. Changes in the database (insert / update / delete) are made only in iOS. In watchOS only fetch records. Records are replicated via iCloud in the devices of the user. With records inserted and updated, replication works fine, but records deleted are not removed in watchOS. Checking the database with CloudKit console, deleted records don't appear in iCloud, but these deleted records, remain in watchOS. These records only disappear reinstalling the app in the watch. Last versions of iOS, watchOS & Xcode are used.

Any ideas what's the problem is?